# Custome attributes that contains Chinese in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I add some custom attributes which contains Chinese in a Spring Boot project. However, the attributes show the wrong way.
I use the idea and set file encoding with `utf-8`.

Oh, and I am using YAML instead of Properties

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

oh, there is no problem.I use the Properties file before, and change to YAML.
So, it shows wrong situation.
I solve the problem by cleaning the project and restarting it.